# How to select distinct values from multiple columns using mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

here is my table:

```
-------------------------
A1   |  A2    | count   |
-------------------------
a    |   b    |   1     |
b    |   a    |   1     |
c    |   a    |   1     |
d    |   b    |   1     |
b    |   d    |   1     |
-------------------------
```

i want to select distinct values from this table with distinct count values.If i use to select A2 column where clause i specified using "b" that time i want result like this

```
A  |  count
--------------
a   |  1
d   |  1
```

Comment: What is the logic in output? What did you tried?

Comment: @user3227658 Please elobrate your question in detail.

Comment: SELECT A1 A, `count` FROM my_table WHERE A2 = 'b';

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this:

```
select A1 as A,count FROM Table1  WHERE A2 = 'b' GROUP BY A1,count
```

It will give you the result:

```
A    count  
a    1    
d    1
```

See [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9c9a9/1)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you need ,

```
select distinct(A2) from table1 where count=1
```

so that you get this output ,

```
A   |  count
--------------
a   |  1
d   |  1
```